# Does the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|\frac{2+7\cos{n\pi}}{n^5+n^7}\right|$ converge or diverge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Does the following series converge?

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigg|\frac{2+7\cos{n\pi}}{n^5+n^7}\bigg|$$

So I was thinking possibly using the squeeze theorem and then comparing to a power series ?

$$-5\leq2+7\cos{n\pi}\leq9$$
$$\frac{-5}{n^5+n^7}\leq\frac{2+7\cos{n\pi}}{n^5+n^7}\leq\frac{9}{n^5+n^7}$$
Since $\frac{9}{n^5+n^7}$ is basically a power series (is it?), then by the comparison test the original series is convergent. Is this acceptable ?

Comment: by comparison test,it converges absolutely

Comment: It would be cleaner to observe that $n$-th term is non-negative and $\le \frac{9}{n^7}$, and then use Comparison with a known series. It is not really right to say that $\frac{9}{n^5+n^7}$ is basically a power series.

Comment: It wouldn't let me post without the title being more unique. 

And so my argument is sound?

Comment: No. It is not a power series, and you only need an upper bound as the absolute value dictates that each term is nonnegative. You can change the denominator to $2n^5$ to get a larger series that is convergent by $p$-series.

Comment: @Clayton:  An $n^5$ in the denominator would also work. However, the denominator is $\ge n^7$, so the inequality as stated is also right. It has the (irrelevant here) advantage of being a little sharper.

Comment: @Andre: Oh! It didn't cross my mind to just drop a positive term, I was stuck on combining the two. Sorry for the mishap.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left|\frac{2+7\cos n\pi}{n^7+n^9}\right|\le\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left|\frac{9}{2n^7}\right|=\frac92\zeta(7)$$

Comment: It should be $\zeta(5)$ as $n^7>n^5$ (unless you are only using this as a demonstration; I just noticed your exponents differ from the OP).